# Цвет фона Floating Label в TextInputLayout

Tags: android, label

При белом фоне ярлык выглядит нормально, при любом другом, используя цвет фона, висит жутким прямоугольником прямо в поле ввода. Как можно сделать прозрачный фон?

UPD: ошибочно считала что ярлык использует цвет фона лэйаута, но на деле label box просто вырезает кусок textinputlayouta, поэтому, вероятно, решения данной проблемы нет... Либо убираем фон лэйоута, либо фон текстового поля.

UPD2: для любителей садомазо и костылей, просто засуньте белый прямоугольник под поле.

[image: Любой другой цвет]
[image: Без параметра background]

[image: finish]

Comment: а что вы за вью используете здесь?)

Comment: Дык из заголовка) textinputlayout material design

Comment: попробуйте убрать фон вообще, добавил ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Создайте стиль:

```
<style name="EditTextHint" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your color</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
</style>
```

Примените его:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:theme="@style/EditTextHint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: @Волчарка, обновил ответ, не вы упоминаете три элемента с учетом родительского макета? вам нужно свои стили определить, либо второй вариант - при определенном цвете родителя менять цвет подложки у хинта.

Comment: Да в том то и дело, что поведение подчеркнутого поля(Filled box) и обведенного (Outlined box) разное, у поля с чертой такой проблемы не возникает. Попробовала заменить заливку цветом на использование обычного цветного вектора в качестве фоновой картинки и нашла свою ошибку. Обновила вопрос с, видимо, приговором(
P.S ваш ответ переводит TextInputLayout в режим FilledBox

Comment: а как вы делаете такое поле? через drawable или как-то по-другому, просто есть вероятность что проблема кроется где-то здесь)

Comment: Это уже готовое поле для ввода от материал дизайн
https://material.io/components/text-fields/

Comment: хм... и правда, но честно говоря тогда совсем не понятно как у вас так получилось :(

Comment: Дописала в вопросе, из за специфики самого ярлыка нужен прозрачный цвет собственно поля или фона лэйаута.